# Moveable Frame on Carpet

Tags: framing, carpet

I am planning on creating a small "door frame" structure that is able to be wheeled out and placed away using a pulley-system. This project is for a performance that will be on carpet and as such I am unsure if wheels would be a good idea as they may end up just getting jammed with any debris or fibres and whatnot. While the carpet is hoovered on a daily basis I'm still worried about clogging up the wheels.

Is there another way this could be accomplished? Alas it couldn't be levitating as I have no way of fixing it to hold the load.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [furniture moving pads](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-Movealls-Reuse-Furniture-Movers-8-per-Pack-83036N12/203566381) that are put under the legs of heavy items to glide them into place.
[image: furniture moving pads]

This version has a slick bottom and is meant to be used on carpets. There are similar ones with a carpeted bottom (or cover) to glide on hard surfaces.

These or similar skids could be placed on the bottom of your structure with recessed screws or other attachment mechanisms.

> Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources

Answer (score 1):

Since you need it to be easily moved to the side during the performance wheels are the way to go. To avoid the problems that you thought of the secret is to use a wheel that is larger in diameter than typical furniture casters or office chair wheels. A rubber or polymer wheel that is 50 to 75mm (2 to 3 inches) in diameter should do the job nicely. You can find such utility wheels at DIY centers and good hardware stores or even online at Amazon (use "utility wheels" as a search term).

[image]

The flat mounting plate makes it easy to attach the wheel to your set piece. You can also build the base in a manner as an inverted box such that most of the wheel is hidden from the side view.

Some wheel models include a toe activated lever to lock the wheels and keep the set piece from rolling around unintentionally.